# This form is not secure Autofill has been turned off only in chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I get this error when trying to fill the form from chrome in my website.
[image]

And this after I submit the form.

[image]

This doesn't happen in any other browser, what do I've to do to make the form secure.

Comment: Is your page served via HTTPS or HTTP? And is the protocol used to submit the form data HTTPS or HTTP? If either of them are using HTTP protocol, then that's probably why. You should never send sensitive data over HTTP, as it's not encrypted and it's "visible to others" Is it possible that this is the problem?

Comment: https://www.androidpolice.com/2020/08/17/chrome-86-will-disable-autofill-on-insecure-forms/

Comment: After some testing it appears that the notice appears when submitting a form to a site with HTTP protocol from a site with HTTPS protocol.

Comment: The only workaround I have found till now is to replace the div element to a form element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of the question.

The only workaround I have found to make it secure is to replace the div element with the form element, but that doesn't give us more control over it, so that's not the best solution, but you can replace the form element with the div element

Answer (score 8):

I have fixed it by using SSL and replace form action http to https. Google work on more form security like website if it's not secure.

Hope this will resolve your problem.

[with http](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBiU6.png)

[with https](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4v1pW.png)

Answer (score 3):

My website is `https`, but I got the same problem.
And I saw

- in the `form` tag I wrote:

  ```
  <form action="http://mywebsite.com/sendMail.php">
  ```
- my `endPoint` I wrote:

```
    post = {
        endPoint: 'http://mywebsite.com/sendMail.php', 
    }
```

No. They should all be `https`.
I've changed them and now everything works fine.

Comment: Great! This MUST be the correct answer! Working perfectly for me!

Answer (score -1):

You should do this:

1. In the form set onSubmit as:

   ```
    onSubmit={handleSubmit}
   ```
2. Create a function to handle submit:

```js
const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
   window.open(`mailto:${email}?subject=${subject}&body=${name}: ${message}`);
 }
```

3.Done!