# the form is not secure. auto fill has been turned off

Tags: html, https

[image: Why does chrome say this about my form when my site is published on the server. I am using HTTPS as well.]

Why does chrome say this about my form when my site is published on the server. I am using HTTPS as well.

Comment: Check web console for any warnings - may give you a clue.

Comment: Is it secure site with https protocol?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [This form is not secure Autofill has been turned off only in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66348773/this-form-is-not-secure-autofill-has-been-turned-off-only-in-chrome)