# This form is not secure Autofill has been turned off only in chrome. Inside all browsers

Tags: php, authentication

I created the login form with php,
How can I troubleshoot?
[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66348773/this-form-is-not-secure-autofill-has-been-turned-off-only-in-chrome) help? I would verify if i was submitting the form to HTTP via HTTPS first and then trying to wrap the form in an actual <form> tag next.

Answer (score 0):

Check the URL of the POST request endpoint using view source or inspector tools on your browser. The URL most likely begins with HTTP instead of HTTPS. You will have to change your code to make sure the URL starts with HTTPS.